# MySQL ERROR 1064 in CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-function

I am unable to debug the code for `CREATE FUNCTION`. It gives the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 16

This is the code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_STATUS(SAL FLOAT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE STATUS VARCHAR(10);
    SET STATUS = "";
    IF (SAL > 70000) THEN
    SET STATUS = "A CLASS";
    ELSEIF (SAL > 50000) THEN
    SET STATUS = "B CLASS";
    ELSE IF (SAL > 30000) THEN 
    SET STATUS = "C CLASS";
    ELSE
    SET STATUS = "D CLASS";
    END IF;
RETURN STATUS; # This is line 16
END; 
$$
```

PS: I have seen other question with same title but they were about the `DELIMITER` so they didn't help.
My MySQL version is **5.7.19**

Comment: Well from what I have read it might be that your last two lines should become END$$  and then a new line to reset the DELIMITER back to ; DELIMITER ;  - This is not tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you change `ELSE IF` to `ELSEIF`. It is treated as `ELSE` and then unclosed `IF` clause, without `END IF`.

Comment: Just saw that there is one of each of the above in the OP's example.

Comment: Ok that worked. But then why It said `error in line 16`, why not `error near ELSE IF` something like that. @Michael O.

Comment: @NikhilWagh Because you've had an unclosed IF clause (part of ELSE IF) till the end of the function.